# Setting up LoadBlancer for direct access to SQL Server with Minikube

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube

I'm trying to setup a SQL Server with Kubernetes. I'm running Minikube locally and I'm having a hard time troubleshooting the connection issue. I have a ClusterIP Service as well as a LoadBalencer Service setup:
mssql-depl.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: SA_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mssql
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: mssqldb
      volumes:
      - name: mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mssql-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - name: mssql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mssql
  ports:
    - name: mssql
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1433
      targetPort: 1433
```

I also have a PersistentVolumeClaim setup

local-pvc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-claim
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
```

After running `kubectl apply -f msql-depl.yaml` this is what I get with `kubectl get services`:

```
NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
commands-clusterip-srv    ClusterIP      10.96.28.141     <none>        80/TCP           20h
kubernetes                ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          2d21h
mssql-clusterip-srv       ClusterIP      10.105.217.207   <none>        1433/TCP         29s
mssql-loadbalancer        LoadBalancer   10.107.63.199    <pending>     1433:31681/TCP   28s
platforms-clusterip-srv   ClusterIP      10.98.35.159     <none>        80/TCP           44h
platformservice-srv       NodePort       10.104.221.184   <none>        80:30201/TCP     2d21h
```

When I run `minikube ip` I get a response of 192.168.59.100 So when I'm trying to make the connection using Azure Cloud I use a value of `192.168.59.100:1433` but I get a generic error (detailed error below). I've also tried a server value of `localhost:1433`, `localhost:31681`, `192.168.59.100:31681`, `10.107.63.199:1433`, `10.107.63.199:31681` all with the same error. Based on the details `Name or service not known` it appears to be network related (as opposed to credentials or SQL Sever specific error). I'm new to Kubernetes, and don't really know how to troubleshoot this setup.

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): Name or service not known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Int64 startingTimestamp)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNICommon.GetDnsIpAddresses(String serverName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Connect(String serverName, Int32 port, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isInfiniteTimeout, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle..ctor(String serverName, Int32 port, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean parallel, SqlConnectionIPAddressPreference ipPreference, String cachedFQDN, SQLDNSInfo& pendingDNSInfo, Boolean tlsFirst, String hostNameInCertificate, String serverCertificateFilename)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlRetryLogicProvider.ExecuteAsync(Object sender, Func`1 function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlRetryLogicProvider.ExecuteAsync(Object sender, Func`1 function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<<OpenAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser/ReliableConnection/ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line 319
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in /_/src/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer/Connection/ConnectionService.cs:line 712
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Data Studio expects a comma (,) instead of colon (:) between IP and PORT for the `Server` value. After using the IP returned from `minikube ip` in this format `192.168.59.100,31681` the connection works.